# MySQL - Using an alias in a subquery with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I have a feeling I am completely borking this MySQL query but I'll ask anyway. I am wondering why I get the warning `Unknown column 'FOO', and how I can get this query to work properly, in 'where clause'` when I run the following:

```
SELECT sample_id AS FOO 
FROM   tbl_test 
WHERE  sample_id = 521 
       AND sample_id IN (SELECT sample_id 
                         FROM   tbl_test 
                         WHERE  sample_id = FOO 
                         GROUP  BY sample_id)
```

*Edit* This query works fine on a different server and fails as described above on the new server. The old one was v 5.0.45 and the new one is 5.0.75.

Comment: I posted something that should take away the unknown column error, but your IN (...), as it is, is redundant (makes a condition that a field value should be in the a set composed of the field value of the same record == tautology). I understand this is probably just a sample, but what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The actual query is rather more complicated so this is simply a test. Since the query worked fine as is on the older server I'm really just trying to see why I get this error on the new server... not make an effective (or even useful) query. Just why no error on one server and why an error on the new server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT sample_id 
FROM   tbl_test outter 
WHERE  sample_id = 521 
       AND sample_id IN (SELECT sample_id 
                         FROM   tbl_test 
                         WHERE  sample_id = outter.sample_id 
                         GROUP  BY sample_id)
```

Comment: That is giving me:
Unknown column 'outter.FOO' in 'where clause'

Comment: Sorry, getting tired. Edited in place.

Comment: Bingo... that did it. Thanks, go get some sleep.